# Java error, cannot find symbol - class string

Tags: java

I am trying to get my code to create the new constructor objects which I require to create a mobile phone object. I have tried naming the constuctor fields to create the object.

UPDATE: I have amended `string` to be `String`, however now when I update it I get the error:

```
error: constructor Mobile(java.lang.String,int,int,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String) is already defined in class Mobile
```

This error comes up at the bottom of the page at:

```
public Mobile(String MobilephoneType, int Mobilescreensize, int Mobilememorycardcapacity, String newserviceprovider, int Mobilecameraresolution,
        String MobileGPS) {
```

What does this error mean?

The code so far:

```
/**
 * to write a simple java class Mobile that models a mobile phone.
 * 
 * @author (Lewis Burte-Clarke) 
 * @version (14/10/13)
 */
public class Mobile

{
    // type of phone
    private String phonetype;
    // size of screen in inches
    private int screensize;
    // menory card capacity
    private int  memorycardcapacity;
    // name of present service provider
    private String serviceprovider;
    // type of contract with service provider
    private int typeofcontract;
    // camera resolution in megapixels
    private int cameraresolution;
    // the percentage of charge left on the phone
    private int checkcharge;
    // wether the phone has GPS or not
    private String GPS;
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;

    // The constructor method

    public Mobile(String mobilePhoneType, int mobileScreenSize,
            int mobileMemoryCardCapacity, String newserviceprovider, int mobileCameraResolution,
            String mobileGPS) {
        this.phonetype =  mobilePhonetype;
        this.screensize = mobileScreensize;
        this.memorycardcapacity = mobileMemoryCardCapacity;
        this.cameraresolution = mobileCameraResolution;
        this.GPS = mobileGPS;

        // you do not use this ones during instantiation,you can remove them if you do not need or assign them some  default values 
        this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        this.typeofcontract = 12;
        this.checkcharge = checkcharge;

    }

    // A method to display the state of the object to the screen
    public void displayMobileDetails() {
        System.out.println("phonetype: " + phonetype);
        System.out.println("screensize: " + screensize);
        System.out.println("memorycardcapacity: " + memorycardcapacity);
        System.out.println("cameraresolution: " + cameraresolution);
        System.out.println("GPS: " + GPS);
         System.out.println("serviceprovider: " + serviceprovider);
        System.out.println("typeofcontract: " + typeofcontract);

    }

    public Mobile(String MobilephoneType, int Mobilescreensize, int Mobilememorycardcapacity, String newserviceprovider, int Mobilecameraresolution,
            String MobileGPS) {
        this.phonetype = Mobilephonetype;
        this.screensize = 3;
        this.memorycardcapacity = 4;
        this.cameraresolution = 8;
        this.GPS = GPS;
        this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        this.typeofcontract = 12;
        this.checkcharge = checkcharge;


    }

}

 class mymobile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", "3", "4", "8",
                "GPS");
        Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Blackberry", "3.", "4",
                "8", "GPS");
        Samsung.displayMobileDetails();
        Blackberry.displayMobileDetails();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error "Constructor mobile (java.lang.String,int,int,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String) is already defined in a class mobile" means exactly what it says. You have two constructors with the same signature. Just delete one of the duplicate constructors.

Comment: If you have a new question, then ASK a new question.  Don't edit one question to turn it into another one.  Otherwise, Stack Overflow gets stuck with a question, and some answers that just don't match it. ... And the compiler error means exactly what it says.  You're defining a constructor `Mobile(String,int,int,String,int,String)` when you've already GOT a constructor with those parameters.

Answer (score 7):

`string` should be uppercase S. You have your string type as lower case `s`

```
private String phonetype;
```

Java is case-sensitive. `String` is a class that extends from the Object class, which is why it's capitalized, just like `Integer`. However, primitive types are not capitlized (i.e. `boolean`, `int`, `char`).

Answer (score 4):

Java is case sensitive. Use uppercase `S` for `String`

```
private String phonetype;
```

Object names (aka reference types) always start with an uppercase letter. Core classes follow Oracle's naming conventions. Read about them [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 0):

Make the s in string capitalized.  It's case sensative.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: UPDATE amended and changed to Upper case S on String, however now when i update it says error: Constructor mobile (java.lang.String,int,int,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String) is already defined in a class mobile,

however Error comes up at the bottom of the page: public Mobile(String MobilephoneType, int Mobilescreensize, int Mobilememorycardcapacity, String newserviceprovider, int Mobilecameraresolution, String MobileGPS) {

what does this mean??

Comment: You have two exactly similar constructors.  Remove lines 59-71 in the code that you posted.
And when you create your Mobile objects, integers aren't passed as strings.  So get rid of the quotes.  

Also your values must match as you put it into the constructor.  So when creating your Mobile objects you have to give the parameters in the same order as they're listed in the constructor.

Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3
                "GPS");
where 1024=screen size, 2 = memory card capacity, "verizon"=service provider, 3=resolution, and "GPS"=gps.